# Tabularx problem

Tags: tabularx

I always used tabularx withouth any problem, but now I can't make it work anymore and I don't understand why. Could you tell me what's the problem ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand\ie[1]{\textipa{\itshape{#1}}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}

 \newcommand{\og}{\guillemotleft~}
 \newcommand{\fg}{~\guillemotright}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.20cm, bottom=2.20cm]{geometry}

 \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum

\begin{tabularx}{ |c|c|c|c| }
\hline inf. & part. pass. it. & part. pass. lat. & derivé \\  
\hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione \\  
\hline cedere & ceduto & cessus & cessione \\   
\hline convenire & convenuto & conventus & convenzione \\   
\hline intervenire  & intervenuto & interventus & intervenzione \\   
\hline possedere & posseduto & possessus & possessione \\   
\hline perdere  & perduto & perditus & perdizione \\   
\hline precedere & preceduto & praecessus & precessione \\    
\hline procedere & proceduto & processus & processione \\  
\hline premere  & premuto & pressus & pressione \\   
\hline ricevere & ricevuto & receptus & ricezione \\   
\hline riflettere   & riflettuto & reflexus & riflessione \\   
\hline ripetere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\  
\hline ritenere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\   
\hline vendere  & venduto & venditus & vendizione \\      
\hline volere & voluto & \emptyset & volizione 
\end{tabularx} 

 \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: tabularx takes two arguments: width and preamble definition.

Comment: Use `\begin{tabularx}{<length>}{|c|c|c|c|}`. Also, embed `\emptyset` with `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE has multiple problems. Two of them are already indicated in comments above, others are indicated in Mico's answer.

Beside this, please in future make your MWE really minimal. Most of the loaded packages are unnecessary to reproduce your problem. After stripping them out and consider the suggestions in the comments, below is a MWE which shows four cases of a design of your table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.20cm, bottom=2.20cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}% <-- added
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

\bigskip\noindent%
first case:
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |c|c|c|c| }
\hline inf. & part. pass. it. & part. pass. lat. & derivé       \\
\hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione                      \\
\hline cedere & ceduto & cessus & cessione                      \\
\hline volere & voluto & $\emptyset$ & volizione
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
second case (with simple tabular, recommended):
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
\hline inf. & part. pass. it. & part. pass. lat. & derivé       \\
\hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione                      \\
\hline volere & voluto & $\emptyset$ & volizione                \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
third case correct use of tabularx):
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\hsize}{ |X|X|X|X| }
\hline inf. & part. pass. it. & part. pass. lat. & derivé       \\
\hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione                      \\
\hline cedere & ceduto & cessus & cessione                      \\
\hline volere & voluto & $\emptyset$ & volizione                \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
but for nice looking table (in my eyes) let employ `booktabs` package and thair `toprule` and `bottom` rule with tabular:
 \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{l} }
    \toprule
inf. & part. pass. it. & part. pass. lat. & derivé       \\
bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione                      \\
volere & voluto & $\emptyset$ & volizione                \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
 \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This MWE gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me that a `tabularx` environment -- with its width set to `\textwidth`, presumably -- is optimal for the table at hand. An ordinary centered `tabular` environment should do fine. If you do wish to use a `tabularx` environment, be sure to (a) supply the desired width of the environment as one of the arguments and (b) to use (suitable variants of) the `X` column type so that the table will, in fact, occupy the desired width.

The following screenshot shows the resulting looks of the two tabular possibilities. Note that I've removed all non-essential package loading instructions from the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm, vmargin=2.2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

%% First Possibility: "tabular" environment inside a "center" environment

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
\hline inf. & part.\ pass.\ it. & part.\ pass.\ lat. & derivé \\  
\hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione \\  
\hline cedere & ceduto & cessus & cessione \\   
\hline convenire & convenuto & conventus & convenzione \\   
\hline intervenire  & intervenuto & interventus & intervenzione \\   
\hline possedere & posseduto & possessus & possessione \\   
\hline perdere & perduto & perditus & perdizione \\   
\hline precedere & preceduto & praecessus & precessione \\    
\hline procedere & proceduto & processus & processione \\  
\hline premere & premuto & pressus & pressione \\   
\hline ricevere & ricevuto & receptus & ricezione \\   
\hline riflettere & riflettuto & reflexus & riflessione \\   
\hline ripetere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\  
\hline ritenere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\   
\hline vendere & venduto & venditus & vendizione \\      
\hline volere & voluto & -- & volizione \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

%% Second possibility: "tabularx" env. w/ width of text block
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |C|C|C|C| }
\hline inf. & part.\ pass.\ it. & part.\ pass.\ lat. & derivé \\  
\hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione \\  
\hline cedere & ceduto & cessus & cessione \\   
\hline convenire & convenuto & conventus & convenzione \\   
\hline intervenire & intervenuto & interventus & intervenzione \\   
\hline possedere & posseduto & possessus & possessione \\   
\hline perdere & perduto & perditus & perdizione \\   
\hline precedere & preceduto & praecessus & precessione \\    
\hline procedere & proceduto & processus & processione \\  
\hline premere & premuto & pressus & pressione \\   
\hline ricevere & ricevuto & receptus & ricezione \\   
\hline riflettere & riflettuto & reflexus & riflessione \\   
\hline ripetere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\  
\hline ritenere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\   
\hline vendere & venduto & venditus & vendizione \\      
\hline volere & voluto & -- & volizione \\
\hline
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```